# monero-miner.com "minimum withdrawal amount"

Tags: mining, mining-software

I've been having a look at a website suggested to me called www.monero-miner.com - I'm not sure how legit it is, basically it claims to be able to mine inside the browser and deposit the coins you earn into your wallet.

Scrolling down, as part of the blurb, it states ***"Payments are done automatically to your wallet once you reach the minimum withdrawal amount"***.

Is there a standard minimum withdrawal amount? Or can this vary from service to service? Because the website doesn't seem to state it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, regarding this particular website, I can't say one way or another whether it's "legit" or not.  Do as much research as necessary to determine whether it is.  Considering you're not risking any coins in your wallet - that is, you're only risking not receiving the coins to which you are entitled from mining - the risk of loss is at least low.

Regarding minimum payout, you'll find that they vary from service to service.  Some mining pools allow one to set a minimum payout to 0.3 Monero, or sometimes less.  The default tends to be 1.0 Monero.  Many miners probably increase the payout threshold beyond that.

Transaction fees are related to the size of the transaction (in kB).  If you need to spend 1.0 Monero, and you have a 1.0 Monero output to spend, the fee to send that transaction will be much cheaper than if you had to use four 0.3 Monero outputs.  Keep this relationship in mind when choosing your payout threshold, assuming you're able to choose it.